# What is a forwarded clock?

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm reading the overview book of the Intel QuickPath Interconnect and it says there:

> The physical connectivity of each interconnect link is made up of twenty differential signal pairs plus a differential forwarded clock.

I can't find what is a forwarded clock, does anyone know what it is and if there is some material for reading about it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-synchronous

Comment: That is excellent, really explains a lot. Thank you! I really didn't find this even though I search for clock signaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [lecture notes of Sam Palermo](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/spalermo/ecen689/lecture25_ee689_clocking_arch.pdf), there are three common I/O clocking architectures:

- [Common clock (synchronous)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_circuit)
- [Forward clock (source synchronous)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-synchronous)
- [Embedded clock (clock recovery)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery)